# how to represent a item in a list python

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples, like this:

```
[(time1, hashusi, servername, uri, referrer, useragent),
 (time2, hashusi, servername, uri, referrer, useragent),
 (time3, srcip, code, mime),
 (time4, hashusi, servername, uri, referrer, useragent),
 (time5, srcip, code, mime) ...]
```

If the length of the item is 6, it means it is a request, otherwise it's a response, now I need to pair all the requests and responses in this list, they are already sorted by time, as you can see in this example, the first two items are both request.

I want to go through the items one by one, if a request is followed by a response, then they are a pair, I will assign a number for them. If a request is followed by a request, then the first request should be discard and to check if the second one is followed by a response, etc

```
for item in mergelistsorted:
    if len(item) == 6 and flag == None: #The first item is a request
       ##need to check the next item##
       if len(next item) == 6:
          continue
       else:
          requestlist.append((item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3]))
```

I don't know how to refer to the "next item"

Comment: There are times when the `for x in seq` metaphor doesn't work. This is one of them. You'll need to play with `seq[i]` and `seq[i+1]` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define this method ([source](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)
```

Then use this loop:

```
for curr, next in pairwise(list):
```

The caveat of this is that you won't get the last item in the `curr`--the last iteration will be `(next_to_last, last)`.  If you want to get `(last, None)` in your final iteration you need to change `izip` to `izip_longest` in the `pairwise` definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through pairs with a loop like this:

```
for prv, nxt in zip(ls[:-1], ls[1:]):
   ...
```

For example:

```
ls = [
    'request1',
    'request2',
    'request3',
    'response3',
    'request4',
    'response4',
]

for prv, nxt in zip(ls[:-1], ls[1:]):
    if 'request' in prv and 'response' in nxt:
        print prv, nxt
```

Comment: zipped sequences are indeed nice, but it doesn't address the "check if the second one is followed by a response" bit in the original question

Comment: @msw: unless I misunderstood the question, it seems it does.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `for item in list`, use `for index in range(len(list))`.

Then you can refer to `item` as `list[index]`, and `next item` will be `list[index+1]`.

Comment: for index, item in enumerate(list) is more pythonic